# How can I add accessibility content to HTML 'label' element?

Tags: html, accessibility, forms, screen-readers

I just want to add some more additional content inside `label` for accessibility purpose. I have include content inside `span` with visually hidden class. But, the screen reader (NVDA) doesn't recognise additional content.

```
<label for="nameInput"> 
  Name: <span class="sr-only">your name </span> 
</label>
<input id="nameInput" class="components-input" />
```

I can't replace `<label>` to any other like `<p aria-label>` or some other tag.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your specific example, why don't you just use 'Your name:' or 'Full name:' inside the label, then you will not need to add in any additional content?

Comment: `Name: your name [_______]` definitely does not make sense.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to clarify that "Name" means "your name" only for people who use screen readers?

Comment: i just use "name" & "your name" as example.. my actual content was different from this

Comment: @webspicer If you could provide a more detailed example that reflects more of what you are trying to achieve will help you receive a more accurate answer.

Comment: @ShannonYoung thanks for your reply. i will try improve from next question

Comment: You can [edit] your question to change the example to a realistic one.

Answer (score 2):

`aria-label` **does** work with non-semantic elements such as `<div>` and `<span>` but you must give the element a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions).  You need both a label and a role for the screen reader to read it.

I ran your code sample verbatim and it worked fine with firefox 61 (quantum) and nvda 20182.1.  It also worked with JAWS 2018 and ie 11.

It sounds like you might have something else wrong.  Do you have a working example (codepen or production site) to try?  Did you try your code with another screen reader or another browser?

Answer (score 0):

The `aria-label` attribute applies to all elements. You don't need to use a paragraph.

Comment: yes, i used aria-label inside the label tag, but, NVDA doesn't recognise aria-label content

Comment: I found aria-label is not working with representational elements like div, span. please read this [NVDA Fails](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/7807) & [paciellogroup](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2017/07/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/)